# Don't execute jenkins job if svn polling failed

Tags: svn, jenkins, proxy

I have a jenkins job, that is polling svn every 5 minutes and executing my unittests if some changes occured.

My probleme is, the svn polling fails randomly due to a unreachable proxy.

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: HTTP proxy authorization failed
```

I guess this problem is related to some issues with the proxy we use and not the configuration of my job or machine.

My question now is, can I skip the job if the svn poll is failing and only execute if it was succesful?
So that I don't have failed builds in my job list because of the proxy issue.

Or does anyhow have an idea why this random error can occure?

Fyi, I don't want the proxy problem itself fixed, as this is probably happening due to network problems, but I just want to skip the execution of the job if the svn poll fails.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polling svn, you can try a post-commit hook so that svn notifies Jenkins of changes; see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin?focusedCommentId=43352266

Comment: I can't set a hook on server side, as the Jenkins Server is running locally on my machine. So I can not send the request as mentioned in the hook to my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent running next action when the previous action is failed,
add set +e to the top of your shell script. 
-e option is exit immediately when any action returns 1(which means failed). And also. @mikep's answer is useful thought. Instead of polling, Post-commit hook is more efficient.

Comment: Is this only affecting the actions I take in my shell script or is it also covering the steps from the svn Plugin?

Comment: it will affect every steps